# 2 SelectMenu in one message discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to add 2 SelectMenus in one message and get the data from both, but so far, all I've managed is to retrieve data from only one SelectMenu.

```
@bot.tree.command(name='command', description="desc")
@app_commands.describe()
async def thematic_day(interaction: discord.Interaction):

    class MyView(discord.ui.View):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.select_1 = discord.ui.Select(options=[discord.SelectOption(label=_['name']) for _ in config_data['list']])
            self.select_1.callback = self.callback_1
            self.add_item(self.select_1)
            self.select_2 = discord.ui.Select(options=[discord.SelectOption(label=missing_date.replace('-', '.')) for missing_date in results])
            self.add_item(self.select_2)

        async def callback_1(self):
            pass
            # do something

    with SchedulerManager() as sm:

        def get_missing_dates():
            pass
            # getting some data from database


        try:
            results = get_missing_dates()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        view = MyView()

        await interaction.response.send_message(view=view)
```

I've tried creating separate callbacks for each menu (data was coming from the one where the first selection was made), attempted to show one menu first and then the other (resulting in the loss of the first selection), tried adding a 'submit' button, but none of these approaches led to a solution.